# Multiframe Carousel

Tags: web-part, sharepoint-addin

My client is looking to display a range of logos on their public facing sharepoint 2013 site and cycle through them automatically. I can't for the life of me find a user friendly solution to this.

Any ideas at all would be gratefully appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those looking for an answer, the Cycle2 plugin that Jinxed recommended in the comments offered the desired solution. (Albeit a little changes to the css were required)

Check out [jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/demo/carousel.php](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/demo/carousel.php)

(Jinxed - if you want to submit this comment as an Answer I'd be happy to mark it as the chosen solution)

Hope this helps.

Thanks.

Michael

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery to achieve this.

1. First place an `img` tag to the page as follows

   ```
   <img id="imageRotator" />
   ```
2. Add a new script editor web part to the page OR if it's master page then edit and insert following code

   ```
   var images = [
      "http://www.mouserunner.com/images/FxLogo128x128.png",
      "http://www.emsl.com/emslimages/facebook-logo2013.png",
      "http://www.theecoa.org/iMIS15/images/homepage/linkedin.gif"
   ];

   var currentIndex = 0;
   $(document).ready(function() {
      setTimeout(changeImage, 3000); 
   });

   function changeImage() {
       if(currentIndex < images.length) {
           $('#imageRotator').attr('src', images[currentIndex]);
           currentIndex = currentIndex+1;
       }
       else
           currentIndex = 0;

       setTimeout(changeImage, 3000);
   }
   ```

As you can see above the image URL are stored in an array. You can add as many images are you want. Images will keep changing every 3 second.

**Update based on comment**

Use jQuery Cycle Plugin. [Download](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/download/) the plugin and add following references

```
<script src="/js/jquery.cycle2.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/jquery.cycle2.center.js"></script>
<script src="/js/jquery.cycle2.carousel.js"></script>
<script src="/js/jquery.cycle2.tile.js"></script>
```

Define a div element where you want to display the images

```
<div id="slider"/>
```

Use API reference on how to activate the plugin

http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/api/

Comment: This is great, Thanks for this - but I was hoping to have a MultiFrame Carousel. Like the 'Trusted By' section at the bottom of this page: http://www.flowforma.com.

Any ideas?

Thanks again.

Comment: @Mike_Piercy in that site they are using jquery cycle plugin http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/download/

Answer (score 0):

You can use sharepoint OOTB Picture Slideshow webpart for this.

Steps are as follows:

1. Create a Picture library.
2. Upload the images in the picture library.
3. Add the picture slideshow webpart to the page and configure the webpart to use the picture library created.

[This](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Add-a-slide-show-to-a-web-page-9693e3b2-d04c-43df-b659-5f269625e383?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) will help you configure the webpart.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I was looking for a MultiFrame slider though. (See Trusted By Section at the bottom of this page for an example: http://www.flowforma.com/)

Would this still be possible with the OOTB Picture SlideShow webpart do you think?

Comment: Picture slideshow webpart displays 1 image at a time. This cannot be achieved using PSWP

Comment: Thanks Jinxed, Any ideas on how it can be implemented?

Comment: You have to use a jquery plugin for this. You can use the plugin here-http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/demo/carousel.php.. The same plugin has been used by the site mentioned by you